# Laravel package development inside sail not syncing changes

Tags: php, laravel, docker, composer-php, sails.js

I am developing a Laravel package, I have the main project and the package folder inside the same folder.

```
code
    /mainproject
    /package
```

Inside my composer.json in the main project I have:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../package"
    }
],
```

running composer require for that package works fine and the code works, but then when I make any changes inside of the package, the changes aren't reflected, and so I have to use composer to remove, then re-require it.

I am using Laravel Sail as my local development environment and setting up the repository in the way that I did has created a sym-link in the vendor folder of the main project.

is there additional setup required when doing package development inside Laravel Sail?

Comment: "when I make any changes inside of the package" - why do you want to do that? Never change anything in the `vendor`  folder

Comment: @NicoHaase: Elliot likely meant the non-vendor path from the path repository `//mainproject/../package`.  @Elliott: no idea of Laravel Sail, but there is the a [`path` repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) setting to symlink `{"symlink": true}`. If the docker container has a file-system that supports relative symbolic links, this could be an option. Benefit of the symlink is that you can edit files in `../package`  and they land automatically within the package folder in the `COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR`. May need enforcement or workflow thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal behaviour, you must run `composer update your/package` every time you make a change, so composer tracks all of that. This is due to how it works internally.

In one workplace, I have created some code as packages so it is easier to edit and I do not end up with a giant monolith, so I have created "local" packages like you.

Everytime you have done a change, you must run `composer update your-package/name`.

What I have done to keep it going normally is adding `"version": "1.2.3"` to my package's `composer.json`, like this:

```json
{
    "name": "my/package",
    "description": "My package",
    "keywords": ["my", "package"],
    "version": "1.2.3",
```

So, when I have done a change, I would just bump it like `1.2.4` or whatever the desired number would be following the correct [`semver`](https://semver.org/), and in my laravel's `composer.json` I would have:

```json
{
   "require": {
      "my/package": "^1.0.0"
   }
}
```

So, any time I made a change (and updated the version on the package), I would just run `composer update my/package`, so I have a new `composer.lock` using this new reference, that would update everything in composer.